# R: Searching & isolating multiple first occurences in time series

Tags: r, search, matrix, time-series

I am trying to write a function that allows me to find multiple first occurences of an event in a given year. Events happen to different firms at different moments in time. So an event might happen for the first time in 1980 to firm c and afterwards in 1981 to firm b. In that case, all i need to find is firm c_1980 and the associated value in the matrix.

If however, an event does NOT happen UNTIL it happens to firm a in 1986 and to firm e in 1986 as well, then I need to find as outcome both a_1986 and e_1986 with their respective values in the matrix.

My (2500 * 800) matrix has 2500 different events on the vertical axis and 800 different year_firm combinations on the horizontal one. All values are between 0 and 10 (in the real matrix, in the example between 0 and 2) with the vast majority being zeros.

Example data:

```
av<-matrix(rep(0:2),10,40)
av[1:7,]=0 ; av[9,3:14]=0
av[,c(22,38)]=1
colnames(av)<-paste(c("a","b","c","d","e"),rep(1980:1987, each=5),sep="_")
col.av<-colnames(av)
rownames(av)<-paste("X",1:10,sep="")
row.av<-rownames(av)
```

The main formula I have been using gives the positions in the matrix of the first occurence:

```
first<-max.col(av>0,"first")
```

This works fine to find the first occurence. However, as the data show, sometimes that are multiple occurences in the same year (e.g. event in row 8 occurs in 1980 for firms a, b, d, and e -> given that this is the first year in which row 8 becomes non-zero I would need to find 4 different values as output).

My code so far is basically a patch-all solution

```
avdum1<-matrix(cbind(seq(1:nrow(av)),first),nrow=nrow(av),ncol=2)
avdum2<-matrix(cbind(row.av,first),nrow=nrow(av),ncol=2)
```

Using avdum1 and avdum2 as well as the original row and column names I can then devise a matrix that gives me the first occurence in the original matrix, together with the exact value of the first occurence (1 or 2) as well as the firm-year combination

```
firsttime<-matrix(cbind(row.av,col.av[first],av[avdum1]),nrow=nrow(av),ncol=3)
```

So far so good.
Now, to find other first occurences in the same year, what I do is

```
av[avdum1]<-0
```

This places the original first occurences at zero and then I run through the entire process again, to then expand the firsttime matrix, split up the column names in years and firm names a,b,c,d,e, compare the years and see whether the second first occurence happened in the same year. If it did, I have to rerun the entire process a third time and so on (my real dataset has 40 firms).

This becomes pretty cumbersome so I'm wondering if there is a smarter way to do it? Maybe a localized search once a positive event has been spotted based on the relative position of that event in the matrix?

### The final desired outcome:

(if you copy the example data you can ignore the initial warning when producing the matrix)

for rows 1 to 7 , the result would be b_1984 with value 1
for row 8, the result should be a_1980 with 1, b_1980 with 2, d_1980 with 1 and e_1980 with 2
for row 9, a_1980 with 2
for row 10, b_1980 with 1, c_1980 with 2, and e_1980 with 1

Hopefully this clarifies some of the previous questions/comments

Any suggestions would be very welcome!

Comment: Maybe split your matrix by company and run `max.col` separately on each company?  It's not really clear what you mean by "multiple first occurrence."

Comment: Hi Carl, 
Splitting by company will result in up to 40 event occurences every time (provided the event happens to every company at different times. What I mean with a "multiple first occurence" is that the same event (row) happens to different companies (a,b,c,d,e) in the same year. The option "first" in max.col picks out the first occurence, which is alphabetic so that firms with names a,b,c will be more likely to be attributed to the first occurence than those with names d,e...

Comment: OK, then how about running a loop over all rows, and doing `which(row[j]==max(row[j])` to collect all max values? (i.e. don't even bother with `max.col` )

Comment: Carl, that does not work either as it will merely give me the highest value that occurs in a row, not the first positive value. Nor will it help in finding the second positive value in the same year as the first positive value.

Comment: Sounds like you need to define your criteria a lot better.  What **is** a "first occurrence" , for starters?  Try posting a small, reproducible data set and explain exactly what output you desire.

Comment: If I understand correctly, in a nutshell, you want for each row (i.e. event) _and_ each firm (i.e. "a", "b", etc.) the first year that is non-zero?

Comment: Not entirely Alexis. I want to know the name of the firm and the year (basically the column) that is non-zero first (assuming the columns are ordered from oldest year (1980) to most recent year (2008). The columns are alphabetic per firm and year so the function max.col finds the first non-zero occurence. Sometimes however multiple firms have a non-zero occurence in the year of the first occurence (see row 8, 1980 for firms a, b, d, and e. they all have positive values in the first year the event happens for the first time. I need to find all of them when these conditions are met...

Comment: I edited the question to hopefully make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a shot, although I followed a bit different path than yours. Perhaps, there could be a way to manipulate your data as is to give the result (and maybe, even, fast) but I preferred to use a "long" format instead. A long format can, also, be fastly manipulated with packages like "data.table" and "dplyr".

Firstly, I transformed your `av` to a long format of the following format:

```
#turn to long format
long_DF = as.data.frame(as.table(av), responseName = "value")

#tidy up
tmp = do.call(rbind.data.frame, strsplit(as.character(long_DF[[2]]), "_"))
long_DF$firm = tmp[, 1] ; long_DF$year = tmp[, 2] 
long_DF$event = long_DF[[1]] ; long_DF = long_DF[-(1:2)]

long_DF[c(1,4,5,8,15,16,20), ]
#   value firm year event
#1      0    a 1980    X1
#4      0    a 1980    X4
#5      0    a 1980    X5
#8      1    a 1980    X8
#15     0    b 1980    X5
#16     0    b 1980    X6
#20     1    b 1980   X10
```

From here on, I guess there would be many different and more efficient approaches, but I could -only- come up with the following:

```
#3D array
res = xtabs(value ~ firm + year + event, long_DF)

res[, , 3, drop = F]
#, , event = X3
#
#    year
#firm 1980 1981 1982 1983 1984 1985 1986 1987
#   a    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#   b    0    0    0    0    1    0    0    0
#   c    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
#   d    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
#   e    0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
```

For each 3rd dimension you could search for 1)which values ([row, column]) are above 0 and 2) which of them are in the minimum column available (i.e. the event occured in an earlier year). An implementation of this could be the following function:

```
#function to apply to each 3rd dimension
f1 = function(x) {
      wh = which(x > 0, arr.ind = T)
      wh2 = which(wh[, "col"] == min(wh[, "col"]))
      wh3 = wh[wh2, , drop = F]
      cbind.data.frame(firm = rownames(x)[wh3[, 1]],
                       year = colnames(x)[wh3[, 2]], 
                       val = x[wh3])
}
```

And apply the function to each 3rd dimension; i.e. to each event:

```
ret = apply(res, 3, f1)
#ret
ans = cbind.data.frame(event = rep(names(ret), lapply(ret, nrow)), 
                       do.call(rbind.data.frame, apply(res, 3, f1)))
ans
#      event firm year val
#X1       X1    b 1984   1
#X2       X2    b 1984   1
#X3       X3    b 1984   1
#X4       X4    b 1984   1
#X5       X5    b 1984   1
#X6       X6    b 1984   1
#X7       X7    b 1984   1
#X8.1     X8    a 1980   1
#X8.2     X8    b 1980   2
#X8.3     X8    d 1980   1
#X8.4     X8    e 1980   2
#X9       X9    a 1980   2
#X10.1   X10    b 1980   1
#X10.2   X10    c 1980   2
#X10.3   X10    e 1980   1
```

Comment: Hi Alexis, Thanks a lot for your detailed suggestion. I will go through it in depth tomorrow (too tired at the moment) but I have a quick first question. you use ## long_DF[c(1,4,5,8,15,16,20), ] ## in the beginning. Where do you get those values for the vector for? If I cannot automatically derive them it means I need to go through the matrix manually which is probably not feasible and error-prone...

Comment: @simon_icl : Hm, I'm not sure I get what you're saying, but if you are talking about the values "1,4,5..", I -just- selected a sample of `long_DF`'s rows to show, because `long_DF` has many rows. If you run the code as is, `long_DF` is generated "automatically" using `as.data.frame.table` and "manually" formatting the result a bit (something that is subjective). BTW, excuse my taking initiative of suggesting something else of what you've started, but I really think having data in a more "general" format to be manipulated will be really helpful.

Comment: Hey Alexis, thanks a lot for your explanation. I was just worried that if I needed to figure out the values in that vector somehow your suggestions would not work on a much larger data set. I did not understand you basically picked a sample to show some output. And please do not apologise for coming up with a solution! It's great to see how more experienced coders solve problems by thinking differently. As i'm just converting from excel and stata, I think too much in 2D matrices as that's the only thing I'm familiar with! So many many thanks!

Comment: @simon_icl : You're welcome, glad I could help! Again, note that the main point I was trying to make is to keep your factors (here: firm, year, event) separated in a long-format "data.frame". From there on, you could come up with any way, of the many possible ones, that you'll be comfortable to continue your analysis. Besides, packages exist that can take care both of memory and speed problems of such formats.

Comment: Hi @alexis_laz. I have finally managed to implement your solution and I must admit it works pretty well but I think the code is not exact. It seems to give me the first time an event occurs for the first firm it can find, and then churns out all the subsequent times the same event occurs for the same firm. However, it doesn't give me the first time an event occurs overall. The way to fix it is to change the order of firm + year in your 'res' variable, then it is perfect. I can't change it so wanted to share this with you!

Comment: Oh and if you have an idea about how to turn the outcome of that apply function into a dataframe, that would be awesome!

Comment: @simon_icl : For your second comment, see if my last edit helps. Concerning the first comment, I'm not sure I fully understand. Could you provide an example where "it doesn't give the first time an event occurs overall"? (Or is the result not valid for this particular sample dataset?) What I believe the code does, is to print the first occurence of an event and, if it occured at the same time for multiple firms, it prints them all at that time.

Comment: Hi again, thanks for your proposed solution. That seems to work well indeed (although I found ldply(ret) doing almost the same thing except for the rownames... 
I don't know if it relates to the sample data set but in the actual data set what happens is e.g. : for event x1e2 the result is 1996 "a" and 1997 "a" while the right answer for that event x1e2 is actually 1980 with firms c f, k, m. So I'm assuming the search looks in the firm name column first while it should look in the year column first...

Comment: @simon_icl : Hm, from the output you get, looks like you did use 'value ~ **year + firm** + event' and not 'value ~ **firm + year** + event' when creating `res`? Otherwise, `f1` looks the columns of `res` which are -indeed- the year and not the firm, and I can't see where it goes wrong. If that isn't the case, I guess a sample dataset that reproduces the invalid output would be really helpful.

Comment: Hey, I just saw why this happened in my dataset. I called my column with years "firm" and my column with firms "year"... Most stupid mistake in the book I guess. Anyway got it fixed. I'm on to the next problem, coding 3 year absence of events. Expect a new post soon I fear! But thanks so much, I'm continuing with the long_df as a way forward !

Comment: Hope all is well Alexis. I am trying to use your technique on a bigger dataset this time and the long dataframes do not work anymore (cannot allocate vector of size 2.4 Gb). There would be more than 650 million rows in a long dataframe. Any idea for a work around?

Comment: @simon_icl Hm, this is a lot of data! I didn't ever had to manipulate such massive data so I have no idea on this topic. Do your memory problems arise only with a "long format" or is it a general problem? Have you looked into "ff" and/or "bigmemory" packages, perhaps?

Comment: It's all fine until I want to convert to a long data set. The issue now is that I went from 37 firms to more than 14.000 and hence the length of the long dataset is increasing dramatically. I'm sure there must be a simpler way of doing this without creating so many observations with a zero as value. I'm posting a new question with reference to this one. I was thinking a combination of tapply(df$x, factor, which.min) could do the trick but that seems to return only number 1s (provided the df is ordered)...