# R - Finding minimum values based on multiple conditions and returning one or multiple created strings based on the minimum value

Tags: r, tapply

I'm asking this question as a follow-up to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323931/r-searching-isolating-multiple-first-occurences-in-time-series) which was answered in a pretty neat way by @alexis_laz.
Unfortunately his method (which includes creating a long dataframe with loads of zeros) is too data-intense now the original dataset has expanded dramatically.

The basic problem is this one. 
Consider a dataframe with three columns x,y,z. I am looking for the value(s) of z and x that are associated with the lowest x-value(s) for every y. The ideal output would be a string of the type `y[i]_x[i]_z[i]` with i the relevant rownumber.

Here is a reproducible example
`set.seed(1)`

```
x <- rpois(10000, lambda = 10); x[sample.int(50, 20)] <- NA
y <- rep(LETTERS, length.out=10000)
z <- seq(1:10000)
df <- data.frame(cbind(x,y,z))
```

Desired output (which I found by simply ordering the df and scrolling):

`df <- df[order(y,x,z),]`

1. for y = A, min(x) = 2, with z = 313 => the desired result (NAs can be dropped) should be something like `paste0(y,"_",x,"_",z)` thus A_1_313
2. for y = B, min(x) = 2, with z = 782, 6008, or 7230 => the desired result would give me all three strings, thus B_2_782, B_2_6008 and B_2_7230
3. for y = F, min(x) = 3 and this minimum is linked to 5 different z-values (4114, 4712,5336,7234,7520) so I'd like to get five strings
   ....

I don't expect there to be more than 5 strings as output anywhere in the real data set.
As said, @alexis_laz provided a solution to an almost identical problem (also asked by me) but that solution requires the creation of a dataframe that exceeds my computer power (>2.4GB dataframe, 650 million rows) now that my dataset has increased from 37 to 15000 firms :)

Thanks in advance!

PS: 
I have looked for solutions using `max.col`, `which.max` in combination with `tapply` but none have worked for me so far. It seems that something like `tapply(x,y,which.min)` simply returns a list of 1s in an ordered df because which.min returns the position within a vector/matrix which is always 1 in the tapply function. Hence something that uses `tapply` but returns a rownumber of the df would be 99% of the job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I got bit by a subtle `data.table` behavior.  `data.table` keeps keys on summarized data, but only the ones you summarized on.  So the join wasn't doing what I thought it was doing.  Here is the exact same logic, but with one interim step to unset the partial key on the grouped data:

```
# data generated with `set.seed(1)`
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x, y, z)[!is.na(x)]
setkey(dt, y, x)                                   # among other things, this sorts `dt` by `x` and `y` quickly
sub.dt <- dt[, list(x=x[[1]]), by=y][, list(y, x)] # get low X for each Y, and reorder cols to match key
setkey(sub.dt, NULL)                               # need to remove key as otherwise would join only on `y`
dt[sub.dt, paste(x, y, z, sep="_")]                # now join
```

Produces:

```
    y x       V1
 1: A 1  1_A_313
 2: B 2  2_B_782
 3: B 2 2_B_6008
 4: B 2 2_B_7230
 5: C 2 2_C_2993
 6: D 2 2_D_4762
 7: E 2  2_E_239
 8: E 2 2_E_4581
 9: F 3 3_F_4114
10: F 3 3_F_4712
...
41: S 2 2_S_3113
42: S 2 2_S_7949
43: T 2 2_T_4570
44: U 1  1_U_671
45: V 2  2_V_178
46: W 2 2_W_1817
47: W 2 2_W_2233
48: X 1  1_X_648
49: Y 2  2_Y_857
50: Y 2 2_Y_7227
51: Z 3 3_Z_6526
    y x       V1
```

Edit2: a cleaner version kindly contributed by Arun in the comments:

```
dt[dt[, .I[x==min(x)], by=y][, V1]]
```

Comment: Hi @BrodieG, thanks a lot for this suggestion. I'm not sure whether it actually solves my problem though. Running your code I end with 9980 solutions which seems way too much. There should only be as many solutions as there are different y-variables (so 26), taking into account that per y-variable there might be multiple solutions (e.g the minimum x=3 is found at different values of y = G and to each of these y_x combinations another z-value gets attached. Should have set a seed, will do now and edit my question

Comment: I see you set.seed at 1. So what I am after is only the minimum solution (basically only A_1_313 for A). It's eliminating all the others that's the problem.

Comment: @simon_icl, yes, I used `set.seed(1)`.  See update.  It's even easier if you just want the lowest X/Z value for each Y.

Comment: thanks for your fast response. This goes a long way but the main challenge remains to get all the values for z for every y where x = min(x). As said in the edit and comment. There are likely to be multiple solutions per combination of y & min(x)

Comment: Some context: y represents an event, x a year and z an individual experiencing the event. I need to find for each event y, all the individuals that experienced the event in the same FIRST year. So if an event affects 2 people Brodie and Simon in 1990 and 1 person Zelly in 1989 and zero people before 1989, I only need Zelly_1989_event240. But if there are 3 others who experienced the event before Zelly, say in 1985, then I need those three names...

Comment: @simon_icl, sorry, I made a mistake.  The original code was supposed to do what you wanted.  See update.

Comment: An iterative way in which your current result is stored and subtracted from the entire data.table could potentially work. What it would need is a way of doing this in a simple fashion and a test to see whether the new x values are the same as the ones in the subtracted result...

Comment: @simon_icl, doesn't the updated result do what you want (for each Y, find the lowest X value, and then get all Y-X-Zs that correspond to that Y-lowest X combination?

Comment: For example, for event `B`, individuals 782, 6008, and 7230 all experienced it on the first year event `B` occurred (year 2).

Comment: Wowowowow. I can't believe how fast this went. It took literally less than 1.5 seconds to run this over more than 150.000 rows. That is some powerful programming. Thank you so much. I am really going to study subsetting in data.tables. That's going to save me heaps of time. Thanks so much @BrodieG !

Comment: After you set the key of `dt`, it's just: `dt[J(unique(y)), mult="first"]`

Comment: @Arun, I think (could be wrong) that this only returns the first item for each value of `Y`.  OP wants every item with the lowest value of `X` (notice how for `a=="B"` there are three results).  That said, I did not know / forgot about `mult` so thanks for sharing.

Comment: I see. Then, after setting key, how about this? `dt[dt[, .I[x==min(x)], by=y][, V1]]`

Comment: Also, doing a reorder with `dt[, list(y,x)]` being a subset operation will result in a copy. The idiomatic way is to use `setcolorder`.

Comment: Yes, much better.  Need to sit down again with the manual and read through all the functions.  I did this 1-2 years ago, but I've forgotten a lot of this / a lot has been added.  One of the challenges with `data.table` is so much of the R idiomatic approach is slow with it.  This makes sense given `data.table` is trying to address slowness by explicitly doing stuff in non-R ways, but it also means I need to go do my homework.

Comment: @Arun, and btw, one of the awesome things about `data.table` is that it still works fine with the R idiomatic approach, even if it isn't always the fast solution.